# Python 3 Special characters escaping

Tags: python, string, html, python-3.x

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen


address='http://www.iitb.ac.in/acadpublic/RunningCourses.jsp?deptcd=EE&year=2012&semester=1'
source= urlopen(address).read()
source=str(source)


from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_data(self, data):
            x=str(data)
            if x != ('\r\n\t\t\t\t') or ('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t') or ('\r\n\r\n\t\t\t'):
                print("Encountered some data:",x)

parser = MyHTMLParser(strict=False)
parser.feed(source)
```

The above code isn't working. It is still printing '\r\n\t\t\t\t' stuff. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
if x != ('\r\n\t\t\t\t') or ('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t') or ('\r\n\r\n\t\t\t')
```

should be

```
if x not in ('\r\n\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\r\n\t\t\t')
```

or better:

```
if not x.isspace()
```

Your first code is evaluated as:

```
if (x != ('\r\n\t\t\t\t')) or '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t' or '\r\n\r\n\t\t\t'
```

Notice the last values are evaluated as themselves! Only an empty string will evaluate `False` thus this condition will **always** pass

Comment: It's still printing the \r\n\t\t\t\t stuff. I want it not to print that stuff

Comment: @sgp You should probably just check `if not x.strip()` to make sure `x` is not whitespace

Comment: @jamylak, you mean `if not x.isspace()`?

Comment: It's important to explain why the OP's way of writing the `if` statement is incorrect... `('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t')` and `('\r\n\r\n\t\t\t')` always evaluate to `True` so the overall statement would always be true.

Answer (score 0):

may be the number of \t and \r etc are varying try this :

```
if x.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\t','').strip():
    print("Encountered some data:",x)
```

Comment: or just `x.translate(None, '\r\n\t').strip():`